Solving ERROR: Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B6 when using IMPORTRANGE
I am trying to make a Google Sheets book to keep track of my schedule. When importing data across sheets, I used IMPORTRANGE(url, range) to import data from Sheet1 to Sheet3. This worked at first; however, after using this formula again in the same column to import data from Sheet2 to Sheet3, this error occurred:

Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in B6 when using IMPORTRANGE

I've tried several solutions, such as the UNIQUE formula and so on. However, none have worked for my particular situation.
Why not copy and paste, you might ask: This is because the amount of data I have to import is quite large. In addition, I would like to prevent discrepancies from occurring between sheets.
The formula works in a single cell

However, when adding the same formula to the next cell in the column (only changing the data source from Sheet1 to Sheet2), the error occurs:


Importrange is not used to import between sheets. It's for importing from other spreadsheets.

What formula can I use to import between sheets?

The same formula that you would use on the active sheet however add the sheet name to the reference.  For example, Same sheet: QUERY(A:C, "WHERE A IS NOT NULL"), Different sheet: QUERY(Sheet2!A:C, "WHERE A IS NOT NULL") Different spreadsheet: QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(url, "Sheet2!A:C"), "WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")

The error means that there is already a value in cell B6. If you are not able to clear the value from B6, then move the formula to the next empty column.

I've heard that from other answers before; however, the design of my spreadsheet makes it so that a column is designated for a category of similar values (i.e., the ones that have the error). Would it be possible to resolve the issue without creating a new column? Thanks!

@Newton'scat, please post a new question with enough details, such as a description of the relevant parts of your spreadsheet and sample data.
